# I have Ubuntu-14.04 installed. How do i install Windows 7 on a separate partition?

Tags: windows-8

How do I use efuse? I have never dual booted Ubuntu
This is a new laptop with only one program installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with efuse.  However, you can typically install Windows after Ubuntu by following these steps:

1. Back up your current Ubuntu installation.  Unless there isn't anything on there you would be sad to lose, you should do a backup.
2. Get an Ubuntu Installation CD or Live Boot USB. (You'll need this because Windows will erase grub, the Ubuntu boot-loader).
3. Use a partition editing utility to make a partition for Windows to use.  I like [gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/), it is an easy to use partition editing utility with a graphical user interface.
4. Shutdown Ubuntu, reboot using your Windows Installation Media, and then install it onto your newly created partition.
5. Shutdown Windows, reboot again, this time using your Ubuntu installation media, but don't install Ubuntu; instead select the option to try Ubuntu before installing. When you have an Ubuntu Desktop up, use the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility to get grub working again, and you should be all set.

I realize this description is brief, but there are some very good tutorials on this topic already out there:

- There are some excellent answers to your question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) on Ask Ubuntu.
- [This](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-windows-after-linux/) is another tutorial on the whole procedure worth looking at.
- [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) is a tutorial about how to recover grub after installing Windows.

Hope this helps.